# 401 Unauthorized : WWW-Authenticate: Bearer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jwt, angular7, bearer-token

I've seen similar threads to this issue, but I had no luck solving it.
LogIn worked successfuly but when I try to GET data of the user loggedIn in my home page I receive this error 401 Unauthorized the same erroe is showen also in Postman

My startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        private string _connectionString=null;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Inject AppSettings
            services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
            _connectionString = Configuration["secretConnectionstring"];

            //without this it will define for example id to Id 
            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                    var resolver = options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
                    if (resolver != null)
                        (resolver as DefaultContractResolver).NamingStrategy = null;
                });

            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                .AddDbContext<ApiContext>(
                opt => opt.UseNpgsql(_connectionString));

            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                .AddDbContext<AuthentificationContext>(
                options => options.UseNpgsql(_connectionString));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthentificationContext>();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials());
            });

            // Jwt Authentification
           var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JWT_Secret"].ToString());

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x=> {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = false;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });

            services.AddTransient<dataSeed>();
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, dataSeed seed)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            // global policy - assign here or on each controller
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");


            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });

            app.UseAuthentication();



        }
    }
}
```

UserprofileController

```
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserProfileController : ControllerBase
    {
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        public UserProfileController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        //GET : /api/UserProfile
        public async Task<Object> GetUserProfile()
        {
            string userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            return new
            {
                user.fullName,
                user.Email,
                user.UserName
            };
        }
    }
}
```

UserServices

```
 headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    })
  }
  readonly BaseUrl = 'http://localhost:53847/api';

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) { }

  formModel = this.fb.group({
    UserName: ['', Validators.required],
    Email: ['', Validators.email],
    fullName: ['', Validators.required],
    Passwords: this.fb.group({
      Password: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
      ConfirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    }, { validator : this.comparePasswords})


  });
  comparePasswords(fb: FormGroup) {

    let confirmPswdCtrl = fb.get('ConfirmPassword');
    //passowrdMismatch
    //confirmPswdCtrl.errors={passowrdMismatch:true}
    if (confirmPswdCtrl.errors == null || 'passowrdMismatch' in confirmPswdCtrl.errors) {
      if (fb.get('Password').value != confirmPswdCtrl.value)
        confirmPswdCtrl.setErrors({ passowrdMismatch: true });
      else
        confirmPswdCtrl.setErrors(null);

    }

  }

  register() {
    var body = {
      UserName: this.formModel.value.UserName,
      Email: this.formModel.value.Email,
      fullName: this.formModel.value.fullName,
      Password: this.formModel.value.Passwords.Password,

    };
    return this.http.post(this.BaseUrl + '/ApplicationUser/Register', body, this.headers);
  }

  login(formData) {
    return this.http.post(this.BaseUrl + '/ApplicationUser/Login', formData, this.headers);

  }
  getUserProfile() {
    var tokenHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem('token'), 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.get(this.BaseUrl + '/UserProfile', { headers: tokenHeader });
  }
}
```

ApplicationUserController the PostMethod

```
  [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        //POST : /api/ApplicationUser/Login
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
            if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                    {
                        new Claim("UserID",user.Id.ToString())
                    }),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.JWT_Secret)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
                return Ok(new { token });
            }
            else
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect." });
        }
    }
```

Help Plz .. Thx

Comment: I see your headers missing Bearer Token!

Comment: @TanvirArjel in my startup.cs ??? I've allowed anyHeaders and In Postman it shows the token in the headers and in my getUserProfile
getUserProfile() {
    var tokenHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem('token'), 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.get(this.BaseUrl + '/UserProfile', { headers: tokenHeader });
  }

Comment: do you actually use asp.net mvc or asp.net core mvc?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In my case I wasn't getting an error and everything appeared to work but my API returned 401 every time.
Having banged my head a lot on this.
I had ...

```
[Authorize]
```

on my Controller and found that the site was trying to use cookie authentication so although my JWT worked fine, the lack of a cookie auth made it fail.
I changed the attribute to ...

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

and this fixed the issue as now the controller ignores cookie auth and concentrates only on jwt.
Hope this helps someone

Comment: Super like. This is the problem I have faced and you gave me the right path. Kudos.

Comment: To avoid setting `AuthenticationSchemes` every time add this in startup. `services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = 
 JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  })` not `services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`, the latter didn't work for me.

Comment: For me, adding `app.UseAuthentication()` did the trick.

Answer (score 9):

I found that changing the order of statements was my problem. Configure() requires ASP.NET Core middleware to be in the correct order.

This DID NOT work, and required me to add `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` to every controller...

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

This DOES work:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Thank. It work for me.

Comment: Thanks. it works only changing the order "app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();"

Comment: Worked for me app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

Answer (score 3):

One problem I see is here:

```
var tokenHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem('token'), 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
```

When specifying a `Bearer` token, you need to leave a space between `Bearer` and the token itself, so that the result looks like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization):

```
Authorization: <type> <credentials>
```

In your case, that would translate to:

```
Authorization: Bearer token
```

However, if you look at the code above, you'll see you're actually going to supply it like so:

```
Authorization: Bearertoken
```

which isn't going to work. Therefore, change your code to be:

```
var tokenHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'), 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
// ---------------------------------------------------------^ Notice I've added a space here.
```

Comment: @SouhaKhemiri Have you checked that token has actually a value or not?

Comment: yes it has i can see it throw the postman or the inspector in section application I can see my token

Answer (score 0):

The code you show does not have the UseAuthorization() declaration.

In .NET 6 I am doing:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:XXXX";
            options.Audience = "idwebclient";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey =
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

### Recap

In my case I was not using any Identity Server Yet I was providing the Host as a ValidIssuer.
It validated the `Authority` for the algo and keys which returned nothing, this caused the system to throw an unhandled exception.
Solved this By Removing `options.Authority` from `JwtBearerOptions` in `AddJwtBearer(options => ...)`.

After that I faced the 401 ERROR, resolved it by removing `options.Audience` from `JwtBearerOptions` in `AddJwtBearer(options => ...)`, Also added `ValidateLifetime` to `TokenValidationParameters` (which you can see below in part 1)

---

### Code

PART (1) JWT Configuration

in .NET 6 :

```
builder.services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options => 
 {
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() 
    {
       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = jwtSettings.ValidateIssuerSigningKey,
       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.IssuerSigningKey)),
       ValidateIssuer = jwtSettings.ValidateIssuer,
       ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.ValidIssuer,
       ValidateAudience = jwtSettings.ValidateAudience,
       ValidAudience = jwtSettings.ValidAudience,
       RequireExpirationTime = jwtSettings.RequireExpirationTime,
       ValidateLifetime = jwtSettings.RequireExpirationTime,
       ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    };
});
```

---

### Extra

GET your JWT Settings from Appsettings using Either this
Where

> "JsonWebTokenKeys"

is the name of section in `configuration` :

```
var jwtSettings = new JwtSettings();
Configuration.Bind("JsonWebTokenKeys", jwtSettings);
builder.services.AddSingleton(jwtSettings);

//PART (1) => JWT Configuration goes here
//..
//..
```

OR this :

```
services.Configure<JwtSettings>(configuration.GetSection("JsonWebTokenKeys"));
using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
{
   var jwtSettings = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<JwtSettings>>().Value;
   
   //PART (1) => JWT Configuration goes here
   //..
   //.. 
}
```